# Python controlling figure outputs from functions

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

If I generate a figure from within a function, is there a simple way to not show the figure output? My following function always outputs a figure even when I have a `_` when calling the function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myfun(a,b):
    x = np.linspace(1,10,100)
    y = np.linspace(2,20,100)
    z = a*x - b*y

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,z)

    myfig = plt.show()

    return z, myfig

z, _ = myfun(2,3)
```

It would be ideal to not introduce any more input parameters in `myfun`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def myfun(a,b):
    x = np.linspace(1,10,100)
    y = np.linspace(2,20,100)
    z = a*x - b*y

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x,z)
    return z, fig
```

Afterwards you can do:

```
z, fig = myfun(2,3)  #  nothing is shown
plt.show(fig)        #  now show the figure
```

Comment: Is it possible to reduce your second bit of code to just one line?

Comment: You mean like this: `z, fig = myfun(2,3); plt.show(fig)`? You can omit the second line if you don't want to show the plot at all.

Comment: Sorry, I mean combining `z, fig = myfun(2,3)` and `plt.show(fig)` into a single command i.e. a single line. If this involves writing a lot more code in `myfun`, then it might be more convenient to just have `z, fig = myfun(2,3); plt.show(fig)`.

Comment: I don't quite get your intention, do you want to show the plot or not? Do you want to have a figure handle returned(for example to save it to disk later)?

Comment: I want to be able to show the plot -- this should be a command embedded within the `myfun` function call... but I think your original answer is acceptable anyway.

Comment: I am still at a loss sorry, if you want to show the plot from within the function call then why not keep your original code?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an elegant way of doing it, but including a `showfig` input option seems to work. Let `showfig=1` to display the figure, and `showfig=0` to not show a figure and instead let `myfig` = a string.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myfun(a,b,showfig):
    x = np.linspace(1,10,100)
    y = np.linspace(2,20,100)
    z = a*x - b*y

    if showfig == 1:
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x,z)
        myfig = plt.show()
        return z, myfig
    else:
        myfig = 'figure not shown'        
        return z, myfig

z, myfig = myfun(2,3,0)
```